# How to replace a plus character using Java's String.replaceAll method

Tags: java, regex

What's the correct regex for a plus character (+) as the first argument (i.e. the string to replace) to Java's `replaceAll` method in the String class? I can't get the syntax right.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You need to escape the `+` for the regular expression, using `\`.

However, Java uses a String parameter to construct regular expressions, which uses `\` for its own escape sequences. So you have to escape the `\` itself:

```
"\\+"
```

Comment: I have the bad habit of using '/'s when building the regex and then running .replace('/', '\\'), so that I don't have to type "\\\\" to match a literal backslash.

Comment: If you want to replace a fixed string, Pattern.quote(String) is a very nice friend.

Answer (score 33):

when in doubt, let java do the work for you:

```
myStr.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("+"), replaceStr);
```

Comment: that's not sufficient. the replaceStr also needs to be quoted for replacement stuff. why not just use `myStr.replace("+", replaceStr)`

Comment: Why would the replaceStr have to be quoted?
String.replace() doesn't replace all occurrences.

Comment: Pretty sure (not confirmed) that occurrences of `\n` where `n` is a digit will be replaced by the `n`th capture (which will be blank, seen as there are no captures).

Answer (score 14):

You'll need to escape the + with a \ and because \ is itself a special character in Java strings you'll need to escape it with another \.

So your regex string will be defined as "\\+" in Java code.

I.e. this example:

```
String test = "ABCD+EFGH";
test = test.replaceAll("\\+", "-");
System.out.println(test);
```

Answer (score 4):

Others have already stated the correct method of:

1. Escaping the `+` as `\\+`
2. Using the `Pattern.quote` method which escapes all the regex meta-characters.

Another method that you can use is to put the `+` in a character class. Many of the regex meta characters (`.`, `*`, `+` among many others) are treated literally in the character class.

So you can also do:

```
orgStr.replaceAll("[+]",replaceStr);
```

[**Ideone Link**](http://www.ideone.com/C5g4G)

Answer (score 3):

If you want a simple string find-and-replace (i.e. you don't need regex), it may be simpler to use the [StringUtils from Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#replace(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)), which would allow you to write:

```
mystr = StringUtils.replace(mystr, "+", "plus");
```

Comment: thx for pointing to this. helped me remembering using this non-regex solution in simple cases.

Comment: isn't that equivalent to using mystr.replace("+", "plus") ? replace does not use regex (while replaceAll does).

Answer (score 2):

Say you want to replace `-` with `\\\-`, use:

```
 text.replaceAll("-", "\\\\\\\\-");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String str="Hello+Hello";   
str=str.replaceAll("\\+","-");
System.out.println(str);
```

OR

```
String str="Hello+Hello";   
str=str.replace(Pattern.quote(str),"_");
System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: Shouldn't the second example be `Pattern.quote("+")` and not `Pattern.quote(str)`?

Answer (score 0):

How about replacing multiple ‘+’ with an undefined amount of repeats?

Example: test+test+test+1234

(+) or [+] seem to pick on a single literal character but on repeats.