# How to replace the first character of a String in Android

Tags: android

I am doing an app wherein the user is required to enter his mobile number. In order for my app to be user friendly, I am providing a format for them **(e.g. 09XX-XXX-XXXX)**. After the registration process, the app will automatically text a certain number which compose the user's FirstName, Last Name and Mobile Number. In order for the server to contact the user, I must replace the '0' (which is the first character) with **'+63'**. Can somebody help me on how to replace it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do like this

```
String str = "09XX-XXX-XXXX";
str = "+63"+str.substring(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Replacing the first "0" is as simple as:

`String phone = "09XX-XXX-XXXX";`

`phone = "+63"+phone.substring(1);`

Answer (score 0):

```
String str="09XX-XXX-XXXX";
str=str.substring(1,str.length());
```

try this it will replace first character from the string

Comment: how can I replace the 0 into '+63'?

Comment: give whole text and output to be get

Comment: my number is 07875780025 then it will convert all 0 to +63. i need only first 0 is change.

Comment: Use as mention below
str="+63"+str.substring(1,str.length());

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the first character only if it is written by user use below code it will also adds validation if zero is inserted by user or not.

```
String str = "09XX-XXX-XXXX";


if(str.substring(0,1).equals("0"))
        {
            str = "+63"+str.substring(1);

        }
else
{
str = "+63"+str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just try this..

```
    String someString = "0";
    String str = someString.replace("0", "+63");
    Log.v("hari", "str:"+str);

    or

     String someString = "0 9854172 common";
    String str = someString.replace("0", "+63");
    Log.v("hari", "str:"+str);
```

Comment: This is incorrect , it will replace '0' with '+63' in the whole string . its not what he has asked.

Comment: i may not understand question.

Comment: my number is 07875780025 then it will convert all 0 to +63. i need only first 0 is change.

Answer (score 0):

The question is duplicate of [How to replace a plus character using Java's String.replaceAll method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610333/how-to-replace-a-plus-character-using-javas-string-replaceall-method).
Try the followings.

```
String str = "09XX-XXX-XXXX";
str.replaceFirst("0", "\\+63");
```